# How to Grab Specific Row info?

Tags: sql, t-sql

The below is an example of what will output when you run the query open: select A.DispatchNote, A.MStockCode, A.NComment
from MdnMaster

| MdnMaster.DispatchNote | MdnMaster.MStockCode | MdnMaster.NComment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345/001 | CAL2-01234-010-50L |  |
| 12345/001 |  | FREIGHT |
| 12345/001 |  | 1 Parcel |
| 12345/001 |  | Trk# 1Z8R9V80013141323 - 5 lb |
| 12345/001 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900381868191 -- 18 lb |
| 12345/001 |  | SHP 21401 |
| 12345/002 | CAL3-0121-020-50L |  |
| 12345/002 |  | FREIGHT |
| 12345/002 |  | 2 Parcels |
| 12345/002 |  | Trk# 1Z8R9V80013141323 - 5 lb |
| 12345/002 |  | Trk#: 1Z8R9V900381868191 -- 18 lb |
| 12345/002 |  | SHP 2140 |

I'm trying to do a query that'll grab just the first tracking number in the list. and ignore the second (or sometimes third they have)

The database has blank NComment lines when there's an MStockCode, and then the MStockCode lines are blank for every NComment line so I don't know what I'm doing.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT 
   m.DispatchNote, 
   MAX(d.MStockCode) as StockCode, 
   MAX(case when d.NComment like 'Trk%' then d.NComment end) as NComment,
   MAX(m.CustomerPoNumber) as CustomerPO
FROM MdnMaster AS m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MdnDetail AS d on m.DispatchNote = d.DispatchNote 
      AND (d.NComment LIKE 'Trk%' OR d.MStockCode is not null)
      and m.Customer = 'LAWSON' 
      and d.MLineShipDate =
       case 
            when datepart(weekday, getdate() -1) = '7' 
                then DATEADD(hh,0,dateadd(DAY, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),-2)) -- if yesterday was Saturday, set to Friday
            when datepart(weekday, getdate() -1) = '1' 
                then DATEADD(hh,0,dateadd(DAY, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),-3)) -- if yesterday was Sunday, set to Friday
            else DATEADD(hh,0,dateadd(DAY, datediff(day, 0, getdate()),-1))
            end
GROUP BY m.DispatchNote
```

My issue is that it gives me nothing since I only know how to ask it explicitly that I want the lines that aren't blank. How do I fix it?

EDIT: I should mention that all of the information comes from the MdnMaster Table (which is A) and MLineShipDate will come from B (MdnDetail). I omitted that information because I didn't think it was pertinent to the question at hand.

An example of what I want to see FROM above:

| MdnMaster.DispatchNote | MdnMaster.MStockCode | MdnMaster.NComment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345/001 | CAL2-01234-010-50L | Trk# 1Z8R9V80013141323 - 5 lb |

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns (at least when several tables are involved.)

Comment: A and B are poor table aliases. Choose something that makes sense, e.g. D for MdnDetail.

Comment: Can you update your post with both your sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: How are you defining "first tracking number"?  Alphabetically?  For example, in rows 4 and 5, there's nothing else to indicate order.

Comment: @Tony By line number in the system, so basically first visible in this case

Comment: If you rely on "Line Number" and not a specific property like "Date or an ID" you will get inconsistent results. Never rely on a sort or order to get repeatable results if you are not using a defined column.

Comment: So internally in the `MdnMaster` table, is there a secondary column defining the order after `DispatchNote`?  As I hinted and as @Stephen Caggiano explicitly stated, a query will not consistently return results in the same order.

Comment: Now that you have updated your query, please update your sample data to match, showing data for both the  MdnMaster and DispatchNote, including the newly referenced columns. Better yet, code the table definitions, data inserts and your query in a new [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-). Then post the updated URL back here along with a clearer explanation of actual vs expected results.  Don't make us do all the work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick way to get some results.  Hopefully, it will set you on the right path.

I'm assuming you can specify a second column to determine the order of the comments.  Replace all instances of `Line` below with the actual column name.

```
Select
   m1.DispatchNote, 
   m3.MStockCode,
   m1.NComment
From 
   MdnMaster m1
      Inner Join ( 
         Select DispatchNote, Min(Line) as Line
         From MdnMaster
         Where NComment like 'Trk%'
         Group by DispatchNote ) m2 
            on m1.DispatchNote = m2.DispatchNote and m1.Line = m2.Line
      Inner Join ( 
         Select DispatchNote, Max(MStockCode) as MStockCode
         From MdnMaster
         Group by DispatchNote ) m3 
            on m1.DispatchNote = m3.DispatchNote
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach use a `cross apply` together with `select top 1` to retrieve the tracking number.

```
select M.DispatchNote, M.MStockCode, TRK.NComment
from MdnMaster M
cross apply (
    select top 1 M2.NComment
    from MdnMaster M2
    where M2.DispatchNote = M.DispatchNote
    and M2.NComment LIKE 'Trk# %'
    -- order by ?
) TRK
where M.MStockCode <> ''
```

Another approach is to join to a subselect that selects all tracking numbers and assigns row numbers withing each group. The final select would limit itself to those tracking numbers where row number = 1.

```
select M.DispatchNote, M.MStockCode, TRK.NComment
from MdnMaster M
join (
    select M2.DispatchNote, M2.NComment,
        row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY M2.DispatchNote order by (select null)) as RN
    from MdnMaster M2
    where M2.NComment LIKE 'Trk# %'
) TRK ON TRK.DispatchNote = M.DispatchNote
where M.MStockCode <> ''
and TRK.RN = 1
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/No9gRcyK) for examples of both.

If there is a chance that there is no tracking number, but you still want to include the other results, change `cross apply` to `outer apply` in the first query, or the `join` to a `left join` in the second. A `cross apply` is like an `inner join to` a subselect, while an `outer apply` is like a `left join`.

If you have criteria that prefers one tracking number over another, include it in the `order by` clause of the subselect in the first query, or replace the `order by (select null)` placeholder clause in the second. Otherwise, an arbitrary tracking number will be selected.

Comment: I updated my SQL to add some things I needed for accuracy, but I end up getting NULL for EVERYTHING on StockCode and NComment. See my post. Also forgot to mention that MdnDetail houses the stockcode as well as the ncomment columns.

Comment: I am awaiting updated sample data that matches your updated query and preferably a fiddle that gives us something to work with.